# BehaviourRelay variable remove duplicates

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, iglistkit

Just inherited this code base and I'm not quite familiar with **RxSwift**. I've done some reading but cannot find a solution to my problem.

We have a variable declared. This saves information from a network call, and then is being used to load information to a collection view. Therefore the collection view is showing multiple similar items

```
var allPhotos = BehaviorRelay<[Photo]>.init(value: [])
```

How do I convert it to a set to remove duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let filteredPhotos = allPhotos.asObservable().map { Array(Set($0)) }
```

PS: Make sure Photo conforms to Hashable

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RxSwiftExt](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt)'s `distinct` operator to eliminate duplication in any observable. Infact, it is a good library for different extensions. Install it through Cocoa Pods or Carthage.

```
var filteredPhotos = allPhotos.asObservable().distinct().toArray()
```